# Why is my Room database returning "kotlin.Unit" in my Android Jetpack Compose App?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room

Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at my problem.  I'm a hobbyist trying to teach myself Android coding with Jetpack Compose and have run into a problem trying to understand Room database.  I feel I'm very close to grasping the concepts but I have been frustrated for days at this impasse.

I do have my Room database working in my sample app (finally!), I can add records, delete records, search the database.  All I want to do is sum up a column (findAmount) into a variable I can use in my app.

When I open the App inspector and run this SQL command

```
SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds
```

The query works fine and delivers the correct answer.  In the app I'm missing something my friends.

Here's what I have:

Here's my DAO for the query that isn't working

```
@Dao
interface FindDao {

   @Query("SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds")
   fun getFindTotal(): Double
}
```

Here's my Repository for the query that isn't working

fun getFindTotal(){
coroutineScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
findDao.getFindTotal()
}
}

Here's my Viewmodel for the query that isn't working

```
fun getFindTotal() {
    repository.getFindTotal()
}
```

And lastly, within MainActivity just trying to get the value.

```
var myTotal  = viewModel.getFindTotal()
Text(text="This is my total = $myTotal")
```

When I run the app I get:

```
This is my total = kotlin.Unit
```

I'm looking for the app to return a Double or String.

Comment: You are not returning any value from the ```ViewModel```  function ```repository.getFindTotal()```. Try passing the result you received from the ```Room```. You can use flow to return results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.   I'll Look into Flow, seems like Flow is now preferred over livedata?  Made the following change to my view model.                  fun getFindTotal(): String.Companion {                                      repository.getFindTotal()

return String
    }  and get the following error: This is my total = kotlin.jvm.StringCompanionObject@e6079d

Comment: Still missing something.....